# Is there a way to check Trigger and Key Input at the same time in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The example is below:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Water") && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        //drink water.
    }
}
```

This code won't work because OnTriggerEnter is called once. I know I can try OnTriggerStay but it would be called more than once when I press the E key.

I really wonder is there way to get it work somehow... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You've got a few ways to get this accomplished, but here's two examples.

The first checks the key first, then waits until the collider trigger is called.

```
    private bool keyDown;
    private void Update ( )
    {
        keyDown = Input.GetKey ( KeyCode.E );
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter ( Collider other )
    {
        if ( keyDown && other.CompareTag ( "Water" ) )
        {
            // Drink Water
        }
    }
```

The second here checks to see if the trigger has been called, and then waits for the key to be pressed:

```
    private bool nearWater;
    private void Update ( )
    {
        if ( nearWater && Input.GetKeyDown ( KeyCode.E ) )
        {
            // Drink Water
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter ( Collider other )
    {
        if ( other.CompareTag ( "Water" ) ) nearWater = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit ( Collider other )
    {
        if ( other.CompareTag ( "Water" ) ) nearWater = false;
    }
```

Note, as shown, it's probably a good idea to also disable the `nearWater` flag when you leave the trigger area.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Water"))
    {
        routine = StartCoroutine(CheckKeyRoutine ());
    }
}

private IEnumerator CheckKeyRoutine()
{
    //Uncomment this line if you want to drink for every key press event not only the first one
    //while(true) {

    // yield return basically tells Unity to "pause" here
    // render this frame and continue nfrom here in the next frame
    // And as the name suggests Until the E key is going down
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E));

    // Drink water

    //Uncomment this line if you want to drink for every key press event not only the first one
    // }
}

private void OnTriggerExit()
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Water")
    {
        // On exiting kill the routine so the key down
        // is no longer being tracked
        if(routine != null) 
        {
            StopCoroutine(routine);
            routine = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This avoids that all the time the `Update` is being called without being needed most of the time and does not need an additional bool flag in the class.

---

And now to generalize this (that's just a thing of mine) you could implement a class with callback events instead in order to use it for all kind of stuff:

```
public class TriggerBasedKeyDetection : MonoBehaviour
{
    // e.g. water
    public string TagToListenTo;
    // e.g. E
    public KeyCode KeyToCheck;
    
    // e.g. have a separate class have the Drink method and reference it here
    public UnityEvent OnKeyDown;   

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag(TagToListenTo))
        {
            routine = StartCoroutine(CheckKeyRoutine ());
        }
    }
    
    private IEnumerator CheckKeyRoutine()
    {
        //Uncomment this line if you want to drink for every key press event not only the first one
        //while(true) {

        // yield return basically tells Unity to "pause" here
        // render this frame and continue nfrom here in the next frame
        // And as the name suggests Until the E key is going down
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyToCheck));
    
        OnKeyDown.Invoke();

        //Uncomment this line if you want to drink for every key press event not only the first one
        // }
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerExit()
    {
        if (other.CompareTag(TagToListenTo)
        {
            // On exiting kill the routine so the key down
            // is no longer being tracked
            if(routine != null) 
            {
                StopCoroutine(routine);
                routine = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use this for all kind of interactions ;)